# How to give string value in the query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6

Using VB6 and Access 2003

Query

```
Select Temp.* into NewTable from Temp
```

Table Name storing in Stroutput as a string.

Tried Query.

```
Select Temp.* into ‘ ” & Stroutput & “ ’ from Temp
```

From the above query am getting error in ‘ ” & Stroutput & “ ’.

When i give temptable instead of ‘ ” & Stroutput & “ ’ is working.

How to give a string value in access query?

Need query Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have Access handy, but have you tried removing the single quotes? Like:

```
Select Temp.* into  ” & Stroutput & “  from Temp
```